# responsive typography

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

i have read different articles about responsive typography but have not found a good practice to adopt. If I have to optimize my webapp for these resolutions with a font-size for everyone in graphic source:

320x480 -> 12px

480x800 -> 20px

540x960 -> 26px

720x1280 -> 26px

after my reading I have put in css file this:

```
html { font-size: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; 
                          -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; }
```

then with the Ethan Marcotte's formula I have calculated my first font-size:

```
body{font-size: 0.75em;/*12px/16px */}
```

then with the mediaqueries I have augmented the font-size for the html attribute:

```
/* ===== == = === 30em (480px) === = == ===== */
@media only screen and (min-width : 30em) {
   body{font-size: 125%;}/*20px*/
}
/* ===== == = === 37.5em (600px) === = == ===== */
@media only screen and (min-width: 37.5em) {
    body{font-size: 163%;}/*26px*/
}
```

Is this a good practice to adapt my font to different resolutions?
Do you have good practical examples where can I find this information?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

Structurally, that is how I would do it.  Not sure I would use percentages though in your mq's, I would probably continue on with em's.  Here is a great px to em calculator: http://pxtoem.com/